# How do I get the correct score in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs

I am making a trivia app in React. Right now, my userScore is always showing 0. However, when I use console.log, I get the correct number of answers that I picked. On the quiz page, I get the percentage of the answers correct. So, I have 7 questions for the trivia. I want my questions to be divided by the length of the questions and multiply by 100 so I can get the percentage of questions answered correctly as the score.

I have the useState here

```
      const [scoreAfterQuiz, setScoreAfterQuiz] = useState(0);
```

I convert the score here.

```
    const handleScore = () => {
      let s = 0
      for(let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++){
        if(questions[i].answer == myAnswers[i]){
         // const newScore = score + 1
        // setScore(newScore)
         s++
        }
      }

      setScoreAfterQuiz(Math.round(((s*10)/questions.length)*10))

      console.log(questions)
      console.log(myAnswers)
      console.log(s) // how many questions I got right
    }
```

I'm submitting the score through a handler after the submit button is clicked on:

```
const handleSubmitScoreAndName = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  handleChange(event);
  handleScore(event);
  handleSubmit(event);
  setDisplayName(event.target.value);
  const scoreResult = handleScore(); // responsible only for calculating score
  setScore(scoreResult) // to view score
  addScore(scoreResult) // to add score to the API
  // displayNameHandler(displayName) // add display name
}
```

I'm submitting my score here through REST API:

```
const addScore = () => {
   const newScore = {
    displayName:displayName,
    userScore:scoreAfterQuiz,
    quizId, 
    appUserId:auth.user.appUserId
  };
  console.log(newScore)
  const init = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth.user.token}`
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(newScore)
  };

  fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/score', init)
    .then(response => {
      if (response.status === 201 || response.status === 400) {
        return response.json();
      } else {
        return Promise.reject(`Unexpected status code: ${response.status}`);
      }
    })
    .then(data => {
      if (data.scoreId) {

        history.push(`/finalscore`); 
      } else {

        setErrors(data);
      }
    })
    .catch(console.log);
};
```

Why is my score still being posted as 0 in the API? Here is the console.log:

```
{displayName: 'james', userScore: 0, quizId: 2, appUserId: 3}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the state `scoreAfterQuiz` isn't getting its latest value in the submission payload due to the [asynchronous nature of setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value). Try returning the computed value in the `handleScore`function as:

```
  const handleScore = () => {
      let s = 0
      for(let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++){
        if(questions[i].answer == myAnswers[i]){
         s++
        }
      }

      setScoreAfterQuiz(Math.round(((s*10)/questions.length)*10));
      return s
    }
```

During submission in `addScore`,get the value using handleScore function as:

```
const addScore = () => {
   const finalScore = handleScore()
   const newScore = {
    displayName:displayName,
    userScore:finalScore,
    quizId, 
    appUserId:auth.user.appUserId
  };
  console.log(newScore)
  const init = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${auth.user.token}`
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(newScore)
  }}
```