# React useState not update immediately inside function

Tags: reactjs

I come across this question : [How do I get the correct score in ReactJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72877499/how-do-i-get-the-correct-score-in-reactjs) I tried to solve it.

This is my code : https://codesandbox.io/s/so-quiz-u4s8g5

The state "score" is one step below.
I try to use useEffect but not sure how to use it with function inside button element.